# query to update data in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a lookup table that has following data:

```
AlcoholStatus

Id  Name
0   None
1   Not Drunk
2   Drunk Less
3   Drunk Medium
4   Heavy Drinker
```

Another table reference this table data (ID) and so it acts as a foreign key in another table.

Now I want to update this Table to the following with just data update and delete two row. It gives me foreign key constraint. I did what I want but is there any simple way to achieve this? I also want to update the another table to appropriate values as follows:

AlcoholStatus

```
Id  Name
0   None
1   Yes
2   No
```

Here, Yes means 3,4 in the initial data and No means 1,2.

Please help me how to delete the two rows and update data as above and also update other table to either `1 (For 3,4) and 2 for (1,2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **SQL Server**:

At first update table that has foreign key (I call it `Alcoholics`):

```
UPDATE Alcoholics
SET StatusId = CASE WHEN StatusId IN (1,2) THEN 2 
                    WHEN StatusID IN (3,4) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END
```

Then update `AlcoholStatus` table

```
UPDATE AlcoholStatus
SET Name = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'Yes' 
                WHEN id = 2 THEN 'No' 
                ELSE Name END
WHERE Id IN (1,2)
```

Then delete statuses with `id in (3,4)`

```
DELETE FROM AlcoholStatus
WHERE id in (3,4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try these and let you know surely how I go

Comment: My pleasure! You have MySQL and SQL Server tags, this solution is for SQL Server, I know, that MySQL syntax is a bit different so I am not sure that this will work there.

Comment: It worked PERFECTLY! Thank youso much. This is for SQL only :)